# How to force `git diff` to present whitespace as is

Tags: git, git-diff

Whenever I run `git diff`, it outputs changes log with *tabs* converted to *spaces*. Is there any setting that will force git to present those characters intact as they're in original files?

Comment: did you try -w flag (Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.)

Comment: What do you mean by "tabs converted to spaces" ? Would you like to have a special symbol when they is a tab ?

Comment: @FredericHenri this option is about ignoring changes in whitespace and not about how whitespace is displayed in diff

Comment: @edi9999 no, I just want a tab to be presented with tab and not 8 spaces

Comment: So 4 spaces for a tab ?

Comment: @edi9999 no, "tab", so when I select and copy, it's tab that's copied and not spaces

Comment: I'm not sure that you can print a tab character in the console , if I copy the output of `printf "\t"` , it is still considered as 8 spaces

Comment: One way to "show characters" would be to use `git diff | cat -A` , which will transform all special characters into a readable form

Comment: When I do `cat some-file-with-tabs.txt` I clearly have tabs outputted in console, content is displayed as is. I would expect same from `git-diff`

Comment: What happens if you do `cat <(git diff)` ?

Comment: Try this solution http://xaizek.github.io/2014-06-22/make-tabs-visible-in-git-diff/

Comment: Git diff with the default set of options will display tabs as-is. Do you have a repository exhibiting your problem on a public server that you can share?